# Does anyone is having issues with Signalr client start function with the newest Android webview?

Tags: c#, signalr

i am taking about android 5 and above.with the latest update i am not being to start connection in our anroid devices devices from the client side.start() function is not working correctly but it's not giving me any kind of error.just does not start enymore

Comment: Can you share some of the code that you are using? That would help diagnose the issue faster.

Comment: Please share your code to get a better idea of what could be going wrong

Comment: i think this problem related with anroid version,appication working in android 4.1,5,6